# How To Centre Image in ASP.NET HyperLink Control

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, webforms

My control is as below:

```
<asp:HyperLink CssClass="link-image" ID="Link1" runat="server"/>
```

C# Code-Behind:

```
Link1.ImageUrl = "imagePath";
```

Generated HTML code:

```
<a class="link-image" id="MainContent_Link1">
    <img alt="" src="\Images\Advertising\ImageFile1.jpg">
</a>
```

My CSS:

```
.link-image {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The CSS works if I apply the class to the `img` element but the control can only set the class to the `a` element.

I try to avoid using JavaScript if possible.

Comment: Use CSS: text-align:center;

Comment: I suspect you left out some markup for the image inside hyperlink control - it cannot just generate HTML for `img` tag out of nowhere. Anyway, `.link-image img` will allow you to setup styles of the image tag.

Comment: @Andrei That works! I feel very silly now. Anyway, I left the code-behind which is now included. Thanks! If you post as an answer I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manipulate style of inner tag `img` just use the corresponding css accessor:

```
.link-image img {
  /* style for img goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use CSS:

```
 text-align:center;
```